# Erlang appending double quotes to a string

Tags: erlang

When appending a double quotes with a string, I have a problem that erlang appends /" not " ?

```
Id = "1223",
    Flag = "1", 

lists:flatten(io_lib:format("{xmlelement, \"deliverystatus\", [{\"messageid\", \"~s\"}, {\"status\", \"~s\"}], []}", [Id, Flag])).
```

Comment: A question mark is /not/ sufficient to build a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I tried the code you give as example, and I guess that you are annoyed because the result string is displayed with **\"** sequences instead of the single character **"**.

```
1> Id = "1223".
"1223"
2> Flag = "1".
"1"
3> lists:flatten(io_lib:format("{xmlelement, \"deliverystatus\", [{\"messageid\", \"~s\"}, {\"status\", \"~s\"}], []}", [Id, Flag])).
"{xmlelement, \"deliverystatus\", [{\"messageid\", \"1223\"}, {\"status\", \"1\"}], []}"
```

In fact you have to keep in mind that what you get in a console is an image of the result of the last evaluation. In your case, it is a list, containing only printable characters so the shell has chosen to display it as a string. But it tries to do not hide any information so you have the surrounding " charaters to tell you that it is a string, and the \ before any special character to tel you, in this case the the following " is part of the string and not a delimiter of this string. But internally only the character " is stored. You can verify it by checking the length of the string:

```
5> length(lists:flatten(io_lib:format("{xmlelement, \"deliverystatus\", [{\"messageid\", \"~s\"}, {\"status\", \"~s\"}], []}", [Id, Flag]))).   
76
6>
```

or for an easier test :o)

```
6> length("test\"").
5
7> lists:flatten("test\"").
"test\""
8>
```

If you want to display the string without these \, use the io:format function to display the string in the console:

```
4> io:format(lists:flatten(io_lib:format("{xmlelement, \"deliverystatus\", [{\"messageid\", \"~s\"}, {\"status\", \"~s\"}], []}", [Id, Flag]))).
{xmlelement, "deliverystatus", [{"messageid", "1223"}, {"status", "1"}], []}ok
```

and last for a better result, in order to separate the string from the ok which is the return value of io:format and so displayed in the console, lets add a carriage return:

```
8> io:format(lists:flatten(io_lib:format("{xmlelement, \"deliverystatus\", [{\"messageid\", \"~s\"}, {\"status\", \"~s\"}], []}", [Id, Flag])) ++ "~n").
{xmlelement, "deliverystatus", [{"messageid", "1223"}, {"status", "1"}], []}
ok
9>
```

EDIT:
the return value of io:format is always ok, It simply prints on the console and returns ok. What I said is that with io:format or length you can verify that the string returned by

```
lists:flatten(io_lib:format("{xmlelement, \"deliverystatus\", [{\"messageid\", \"~s\"}, {\"status\", \"~s\"}], []}", [Id, Flag])),
```

does not contain any '\'. If you want to record this value to use it or manipulate it later, just assign it to a variable:

```
My_string = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("{xmlelement, \"deliverystatus\", [{\"messageid\", \"~s\"}, {\"status\", \"~s\"}], []}", [Id, Flag])),
```

Comment: Okay, I have understood your answer. I have another question is how to get the return value of io:format and assign it to another variable Because it prints to me ok string not my string